# Collect serialized items of multiple enumerable members to a same parent

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Consider the following class:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("User")]
    public List<string> Users { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("Role")]
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to transform the class definition to get following expected result of XML serialization for an instance of the class:

```xml
<MyClass id="123">
  <Access>
    <User>User A</User>
    <User>User B</User>
    <User>User C</User>
    <Role>Role A</Role>
    <Role>Role B</Role>
    <Role>Role C</Role>
  </Access>
</MyClass>
```

Moreover it must be deserializable. I tried to apply `[Xml Array("Access")]` attribute to both `Users` and `Roles` properties, but an `InvalidOperationException` occurs.

It would be great if the question can be solved without `IXmlSerializable` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to make an "Access" class to nest your Users/Roles.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Access")]
public class Access {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="User")]
    public List<string> User { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Role")]
    public List<string> Role { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="MyClass")]
public class MyClass {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Access")]
    public Access Access { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So simple?! LoL! Thank you.